# Google Earth Engine Python API - Notebook Authenticator Error "Invalid Request"

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-colaboratory, google-earth-engine

I want to use google earth engine python API in google colab. When I run the `ee.Authenticate()` command, a link is given and it asks me for verification code.
When I open  the link and  click on Generate Token. It gives me the error **"Invalid Request"**. Before this it was working fine and with other cloud projects it can be authenticated but the default cloud project that I  am using, and have installed other google cloud APIs on which it is not working now. Do I need to create some service account / oauth credentials or enable API inside gcloud that I might have disabled / uninstalled?

[image]

I checked google cloud console. oauth consents for google earth engine API is enabled.